# Grails missing configuration from external config file

Tags: grails

I have a problem accessing a value from the config file. During debugging, it seems the values from the external config file are simply not being loaded.

Grails version I use is `2.3.8`, about a month ago was `2.1.0` and it was working back then.

The error I get is

> Cannot cast object 'groovy.util.ConfigObject@149ad0fa' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'java.lang.Long'. Stacktrace follows:
>    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'groovy.util.ConfigObject@149ad0fa' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'java.lang.Long'

`MyClass.groovy`:

```
@Lazy public static Long GROUP_ID_TO_SEND = Holders.config.group.id.to.send
```

It is in `MyConfig.groovy`

```
group.id.to.send = 3L as Long
```

And `Config.groovy` has that config file covered:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.config.locations = [Ldap, Jndi, "file:${basedir}/MyConfig.groovy"]
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Grails 2.3 broke this, it's a [known, still not fixed bug](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11795).

However, I found that there is a simple solution to this. You only need to change this

```
"file:${basedir}/MyConfig.groovy"
```

to this

```
"file:MyConfig.groovy"
```